# Undefined Variable Errors in Syntastic SASS Checker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass, syntastic

I use Syntastic to help catch my syntax errors early.  It's set to also check any scss but errors for any scss files that reference variables defined in my "_variables.css.scss partial.

I'm assuming that the variables file isn't be required into the context, but works fine in the app because of the Rails asset pipeline.

I'm not sure when/where/how to do so to resolve the Syntastic errors.  If I import "_varibles.css.scss" from within the scss file, errors are resolved.  But is there a better way than to do this for all files w/ similar errors?  Any guidance?  Thanks.

Comment: Faced the same problem. Reported the bug - https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/1140

Comment: The problem seems to be in the Sass checker itself. It doesn't include any other modules by default.

Answer (score -1):

Partials do not require the .css extension instead you can just rename it _varibles.scss

Partials should always be imported from your main scss file.

Comment: The .css.scss file extension is a Rails thing.  Partials can be imported anywhere you want.